# How do you add a table list to a ViewModel in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a User model.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
}
```

This is is my UserGroup model that would contain user groups like Admin, System Admin, etc.

```
public class UserGroup
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public bool Admin {get; set;}
    public bool SystemAdmin {get; set}
    public List<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

I just started .net core so I hope my relationship is correct. 
What I would like is to have a User Create View that had a html selection that list all the groups. Something like this but being dynamic.

```
<select class="form-control m-b" asp-for="Role" required>
    <option value=""></option> 
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="SystemAdmin">System Admin</option>
</select>
```

This is the UserGroupViewModel that I'm send to the User Create Form.

```
public class UserCreateViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<UserGroup> UserGroups {get; set;}
}
```

Finally on my UserController I'm going to be looping the List of UserGroups that I got from my database and I'll add it to the UserCreateViewModel.

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        UserCreateViewModel userCreateViewModel = new UserCreateViewModel();

        var userGroups = db.UserGroups.ToList();

        foreach(var group in userGroups)
        {
            userCreateViewModel.UserGroups.Add(group);
        }


        return View(userCreateViewModel);
    }
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error that I'm not sure how to deal with it.

[image]
What does this error means and How can I solve it. I'm also open for a different approach from experience developers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is crashing with a **null reference exception** because you are trying to call the `Add` method on `NULL` . When you create `UserCreateViewModel` object, you are not initializing the `UserGroups` property to an empty list and you do not have a constructor which does the same. So basically `UseGroups` property is null.

The solution is to initialize the `UserGroups`  property before calling `Add` method on that.

```
var userCreateViewModel = new UserCreateViewModel();
userCreateViewModel.UserGroups =new List<UserGroup>(); // Initialize to empty list

var userGroups = db.UserGroups.ToList();

foreach(var group in userGroups)
{
      userCreateViewModel.UserGroups.Add(group);
}
```

Or yo can directly set the collection to that property.

```
var userCreateViewModel = new UserCreateViewModel 
{
   UserGroups= db.UserGroups.ToList()
};
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing groups in a local variable but you need to set the `UserGroups` property on the instance of `UserCreateViewModel`  which you created at start, so just change the following:

```
var userGroups = db.UserGroups.ToList();
```

to :

```
userCreateViewModel.UserGroups = db.UserGroups.ToList();
```

and you can skip the loop that you are doing down there, because we have already set the `UserGroups` collection with the result which was needed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I love the new solution is alot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

**userCreateViewModel.UserGroups = userGroups;**

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    UserCreateViewModel userCreateViewModel = new UserCreateViewModel();

    var userGroups = db.UserGroups.ToList();

    userCreateViewModel.UserGroups = userGroups;

    return View(userCreateViewModel);
}
```

Comment: indeed! was too quick. Fixed! ;-)